# Convert Concurrent Dictonary values to a List

Tags: c#, list, concurrentdictionary

How can I convert the concurrent dictionary values  to list, below is my code which I try.

```
//this collection will maitain server connections/ server can support multiple connections
public static readonly IDictionary<string, ISet<ConnectionManager>> SereverConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ISet<ConnectionManager>>();
//Get All Server Connections List
public static IList<ConnectionManager> GetAllServerConnections()
{

    IList<ConnectionManager> connectionList = new List<ConnectionManager>(Global.SereverConnections.Values);
    return connectionList;
    //return Global.SereverConnections.Values.ToList();
    //return (Gloconnections.ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<ConnectionManager>().ToList());
}
```

Compile time Error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.ISet<ChatServer.ConnectionManager>>' to 'int'
```

Comment: I want to know the reason why my question gets vote down? any reason so I can improve my self?

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted... it's not an unreasonable question from what I can tell... obviously somebody thought it was worth answering.  Please do mark the answer that worked best for you though.  Give somebody the credit.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
IList<ConnectionManager> connectionList = Global.SereverConnections.SelectMany(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<ISet<ConnectionManager>> connectionList = Global.SereverConnections.Values.ToList();
```

this will give you a list of 'ISet' - really depends what an ISet is if you need to go any further.

Answer (score 0):

You passing **ICollection** inside List(**int** size) constructor. Of course, compiler will complain about conversion of ICollection to an Integer.
Also you containing collection of sets, so your commented code will not work, this way you can get all distincted connections:

```
public static IList<ConnectionManager> GetAllServerConnections()
{
    return Global.SereverConnections.SelectMany(x=> x.Value).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have tried however not accepting IList<ConnectionManager> connectionList = new List<ConnectionManager>(Global.SereverConnections.Values.Select(x=> x));